# Returning an array to Twig from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, php, array

I'am writing a plugin that has to return an array of data, however Twig does not seem to accept it if I return a PHP array.  I don't want to use an explode in Twig to make it into an array.

I have seen in other plugins i can just call a function from twig like this.

```
{% set result = craft.winkelwagen.printWinkelWagen(currentUser.id) %}

{% for output in result %}
    {{ output }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I get an array to string conversion error.  Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your plugin should be able to handle PHP arrays just fine.

craft/plugins/myplugin/variables/MyPluginVariable.php

```
function getArray()
{
    return array('hi', 'there');
}
```

craft/templates/template.twig

```
{% set result = craft.myPlugin.getArray() %}
{% for item in result %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

The error you're seeing is likely because `output` itself is an array. If you have devMode enabled you can try a `{{ dump(output) }}` inside your for-loop to see what it actually is / contains.

Comment: i now only have this in twig  {% set result = craft.winkelwagen.printWinkelWagen(currentUser.id) %} But it still gives the error however if i use print_r in php it outputs fine.

Comment: Hang on - the only thing in your template is the 'set result = ...'-line - and you're still seeing a Twig-error about array to string conversion?

If that's the case I suspect that something in one of your other templates (that this one is extending or including) is throwing the error - because there's no way a simple variable declaration should throw that error.